# How do I switch views by using a touch gesture on SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Hi I am pretty new to using SwiftUI. I have been having trouble with adding a tap gesture to my welcome page that will allow the user to move on to another view with drop down question boxes. I currently have this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "Globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Welcome to WOD planner!")
                .font(.title)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .onTapGesture{ action:{
                    //go to question page
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

I made another view labeled QuestionPage. Im just confused how to code this gesture to make it change and isolate the two different views.

Thanks!

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) You haven't provided enough code to give a substantial answer. We would just be guessing your entire setup.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by having a State variable that will track the View that I want to show. Within the WindowGroup in my App, I now present the View that the viewState refers to.

This sample code should do the trick, it will change Views if you tap on the text in the middle of the screen. I personally would rather use a button, but it can be done with onTapGesture:

```
enum ViewState {
    case welcomeView
    case questionView
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {

    @State var currentView: ViewState = .welcomeView

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            switch (currentView) {
            case .welcomeView:
                WelcomeView(viewState: $currentView)
            case .questionView:
                QuestionView(viewState: $currentView)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct WelcomeView: View {

    @Binding var viewState: ViewState

    var body: some View {
        // your view here
        Text("Welcome")
            .onTapGesture { viewState = .questionView }
    }
}

struct QuestionView: View {

    @Binding var viewState: ViewState

    var body: some View {
    // your view here
        Text("Some questions")
            .onTapGesture { viewState = .welcomeView }
    }
}
```